# Which media files does Sitecore 9.0 support?

Tags: media-library

I'm looking for a complete list of which media files Sitecore 9.0 supports. I can't find anything in Sitecore documentation. Only examples. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing like "supported media file" in Sitecore.

You can upload any type of the file to media library. It can be image, video, word document. But it can also be a `.dat` file or `.psd` or even a file without any extension.

The only question is what do you want to do with those files later. If you want to expose a downloadable link to them, it should work just fine.

If you want to create `<img>` tag in your website and use a PSD file as a source of it, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box supported types for Sitecore 9.0 are as quoted:

> A Media item can be:
>
> Images — .jpg, .gif, .png and other formats.
>
> Microsoft Word documents — .doc and .docx files.
>
> .pdf documents
>
> Videos — .mpeg, .wmv and other formats.
>
> Audio files — .mp3 and other audio formats.

source: [Sitecore Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/media-items.html)

In older versions, if you wished to support additional media file extensions you could extend this in configuration by doing a patch file like so, should be same in 9.0 and up but I haven't looked into it myself:

```
// .SVG extension patch example
<configuration xmlns:patch="www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig">
    <sitecore>
        <mediaLibrary>
            <mediaTypes>
                <mediaType name="SVG image" extensions="svg">
                    <mimeType>image/svg+xml</mimeType>
                    <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
                    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/image</sharedTemplate>
                   <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/image</versionedTemplate>
                    <mediaValidator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageValidator"/>
                    <thumbnails>
                        <generator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageThumbnailGenerator, Sitecore.Kernel">
                            <extension>png</extension>
                        </generator>
                        <width>150</width>
                        <height>150</height>
                        <backgroundColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundColor>
                    </thumbnails>
                </mediaType>
            </mediaTypes>
        </mediaLibrary>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

source: [Sitecore Community Forums](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1670)